SonarLint not picking up exception throwing inside "instance initializer block" of an anonymous class
When I have this kind of Java code:
@Test
void testExplainJavaS1130_WithAnonymousInstanceInitilizer() throws Exception {
    var something = new IllegalStateException() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        {
            // This is what is throwing but Java:S1130 does not see it
            throwingMethod();
        }

        private void throwingMethod() throws Exception {
            throw new Exception("On purpose for testing");
        }
    };
    assertNotNull(something);
}

I get this message from SonarLint:
Remove the declaration of thrown exception 'java.lang.Exception', as it cannot be thrown from method's body.

Now I could "deactivate rule java:S1130" but it would normally help me nicely. So I would like the SonarLint system to pick up the actual Exception throwing inside of the "instance initializer block". How do I stimulate SonarLint to do this?
I could live with turning of this rule in test-scope, any help with that would also be welcome.
I'm using "SonarLint for Eclipse: 10.9.1.82333".
PS this indeed is related to the old jmock system I still enjoy using.

If you spot a bug or if you have a feature request, please do not ask a question on Stack Overflow but report it directly to the project, best with a pull request, especially if it is an open source project you are using for free. The rule Java:S1130 seems to be implemented in RedundantThrowsDeclarationCheck.java, see also RedundantThrowsDeclarationCheckTest.java.

Essaye ce code
var something = new IllegalStateException() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    {
        try {
            throwingMethod();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception during instance initialization", e);
        }
    }

    private void throwingMethod() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("On purpose for testing");
    }
};


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
